# NumPy: sort matrix rows by number of non-zero entries

Tags: python, sorting, numpy, matrix

```
import numpy as np

def calc_size(matrix, index):
    return np.nonzero(matrix[index,:])[1].size

def swap_rows(matrix, frm, to):
    matrix[[frm, to],:] = matrix[[to, frm],:]
```

Numpy - Python 2.7

How can I achieve that matrix's rows are sorted after the size of the nonzero entries? I already wrote these two methods for doing the work but I need to give it to a sorting engine? The fullest rows should be at the beginning!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have an array `arr`:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

You could sort the array's rows according to the number of zero entries by writing:

```
>>> arr[(arr == 0).sum(axis=1).argsort()]
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

This first counts the number of zero entries in each row with `(arr == 0).sum(axis=1)`: this produces the array `[5, 1, 2, 0]`.

Next, `argsort` sorts the indices of this array by their corresponding value, giving `[3, 1, 2, 0]`.

Lastly, this argsorted array is used to rearrange the rows of `arr`.

P.S. If you have a matrix `m` (and not an array), you may need to ravel before using `argsort`:

```
m[(m == 0).sum(axis=1).ravel().argsort()]
```

Comment: I have a <class 'numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix'>: i.e. [[0,1],[1,1]]

Comment: You could always write `m[(m == 0).sum(axis=1).ravel().argsort()]` instead, where `m` is your matrix.

Comment: yes that works you will need to write $m[(m == 0).sum(axis=1).ravel().argsort()][0]$